# Making grids using JS or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid-system

I'm new to JS and have been working through lessons via The Odin Project. I'm on my first JS/JQuery project and I'm having trouble with this project:

How do I use JS/JQuery so a user could input a number between 1-16 and a grid will pop out the size of the page. i.e. the user types in 3 and a 3x3 grid the size of the webpage comes out? or a user types in 16 and a 16x16 grid comes out?

I would prefer not a straight out answer, but maybe if someone could point me in the right direction with some starter code? I'm guessing the best approach would be to create a div and use the .append() function? Just need a little more direction here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the cryptic response you require. I've included fill-in-the-blanks and left out how to expand the table to fill the screen. *Hint: use $(window).height()/$(window).width() to get the size of the screen.*

```js
$('#grid').change(function(){
    $('table').remove();
    var code = "<table>";
    for (var i = 0; i < $('#grid').val(); i++)
    {
        code += "???";
        for (var j = 0; j < $('#grid').val(); j++)
        {
            code += "???";
        }
        code += "???";
    }
    code += "</table>";
    $('#container').append(code);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <label>Grid Size</label>
    <input type="number" id="grid" />
</div>
```